# What are the specifications for the CFE738-1-1B?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine

I'm designing an aircraft for fun, and I've selected a CFE738-1-1B as the engine. It's never going to fly outside of X Plane, but it's still fun, so I'd like to make the X Plane version as realistic as possible. This means that I need to know a bit about this engine (it's used in the Falcon 2000, so any Falcon 2000 pilots, not including anything after the 2000 like 2000EX, you would be very helpful). What I need to know and haven't been able to find on the internet is the following:

1. Minimum N2 to avoid a hot start.
2. Length of time it takes from beginning of engine start to idle fuel flow.
3. Time from idle throttle to max throttle.
4. Time for N1 to spool up to max from idle.
5. Thrust curves.
6. SFC at half thrust at 0 and 40,000 feet.
7. Fuel flow at flight idle.

Any help much appreciated (Don't feel obligated to answer all of these in the same post)!

Comment: No guarantees as to accuracy but existing X-Plane models like [this one](http://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?app=downloads&showfile=9727) would be helpful at least as a starting point.

Comment: May be helpful: [Civil Turbojet/Turbofan Specifications](http://www.jet-engine.net/civtfspec.html). Also the Brazilian [type certificate](http://www2.anac.gov.br/certificacao/Produtos/Espec/EM-9701i.pdf).

Comment: @fooot: Thanks, I'll check that one out.

Comment: @mins: Thanks, but those were two of the first things I used (the specifications sheet was actually my main resource for deciding on an engine)

Comment: http://competition.simu.free.fr/cockpit/Falcon_2000_PTM_V2r2_MCD%20Description%20des%20systemes.pdf - Chapter 7 is about the powerplant and contains lot of data. I'm currently at work so I've little time to check, but I hope this could help :)

Comment: That looks like it will be exceedingly helpful.